# How to Join two RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDD as below

```
case class Person (name,age,phno,email)
case class Employee (empid,name,age,phone,email)
```

`rdd1[Person]` and `rdd2[Employee]`

I want to join this two rdd's based on phone and email and need to get

```
RDD[Person,Employee]
```

Can someone please suggest how to do that?

Comment: Join the two rdds on a unique key (possible email?)

Comment: `rdd1.map(x=>((x.phno,x.email),x)).join(rdd2.map(x=>((x.phone,x.email),x)))` will join two RDDs on `phone` and `email`. You can apply `map` after this to get `RDD[Person,Employee]`

Answer (score -1):

Create two data frames. 
Assuming you have imposed schema on rdd from case class:

```
df1 = rdd1.toDF.withColumn("Primary_key_1",concat($"phno",lit("_"),$"email"))

df2 = dd2.df.withColumn("Primary_key_2",concat($"phno",lit("_"),$"email")).drop("phno","email")

rdd = df1.join(df2,$"Primary_key_1"===$"Primary_key_2","left_outer").drop("Primary_key_2","Primary_key_1").rdd
```